# Apache httpComponents HttpClient 4.2.2 unable connect to a web page via Webscarab proxy

Tags: java, proxy, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a method which uses the Apache httpComponents HttpClient class to connect to a web page via the Webscarab proxy. I get the method from the Apache Software Foundation  [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientExecuteProxy.java). below is my hole method:

```
       public void HTTPGet(){
            //HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("localhost", 8008);

            System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "localhost");
            System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8008");

            HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(System.getProperty("http.proxyHost", "localhost"),Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("http.proxyPort", "8008")));
                
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try {

                httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY,
                        proxy);

                HttpHost target = new HttpHost("www.google.gr/", 80);
                HttpGet req = new HttpGet("/");

                System.out.println("executing request to " + target + " via "
                        + proxy);
                HttpResponse rsp = httpclient.execute(target, req); //here I get the exception as below
                HttpEntity entity = rsp.getEntity();

                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(rsp.getStatusLine());
                Header[] headers = rsp.getAllHeaders();
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(headers[i]);
                }
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

                if (entity != null) {
                    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
                }

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(WebBrowser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } 
            finally {
                // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
                // shut down the connection manager to ensure
                // immediate deallocation of all system resources
                httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            }
      }
```

The println before the `HttpResponse rsp = httpclient.execute(target, req);`,

return this : `executing request to http://www.google.gr/:80 via http://localhost:8008`

Then the below exception occurs.

```
Nov 28, 2012 1:23:09 AM student.WebBrowser HTTPGet
SEVERE: null
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:8008 refused
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:827)
```

Webscarab interfere correctly when I try to reach a page from another browser, like Firefox, Chrome or JavaFX webengine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since the connection is being refused, I can only assume that WebScarab is not listening on the port you are trying to connect to (at the time that you are trying to connect).

e.g. WebScarab is not running, or you have configured it to listen on a different port than the default 8008, or on a different interface to localhost (127.0.0.1).

Is your code running on the same machine as WebScarab? If not, you need to make WebScarab listen to the actual network interface that it is reachable on over the network, and update your code to reference that IP address instead of localhost.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem is that I have an action listener on a button, which triggers the webscarab.jar to execute. Below webscarab execution, in the same listener, I call the method I describe above and then the exception occurs. When I open webscarab before running my program, webscarab interfere correctly in the communication. So as I can understand, the problem maybe is that webscarab.jar has not finish its initialization and when I try connect to a page through it my program give the exception above. So it seems that is not a webscarab problem.
Again thanks for the help